# How do I get hyperlinks out of an HTML table using readHTMLTable?

Tags: xml, r

I have an `XMLNodeSet` object that contains an HTML table with hyperlinks. When I use `readHTMLTable` to convert to a data.frame it works great, but the hyperlink info is lost. Is there a way I can create an additional column in the data.frame that contains the hyperlink?

Maybe a simpler example would be extracting the hyperlinks from the table here http://stoptb.org/countries/tbteam/reg_wpro.asp.

```
table <- readHTMLTable("http://stoptb.org/countries/tbteam/reg_wpro.asp")

df <- data.frame(table[[8]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readHTMLTable` calls `xmlValue` as its default for `elFun`. You can simple define a different function to extract the hyperlinks:

```
require(XML)
regURL <- "http://stoptb.org/countries/tbteam/reg_wpro.asp"
table <- readHTMLTable(regURL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- table[[8]]


hrefFun <- function(x){
  xpathSApply(x,'./a',xmlAttrs)  
}
table2 <- readHTMLTable(regURL, elFun = hrefFun, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- table2[[8]]

df$URLS <- df2$V2
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great! (And now I understand a bit more how this all works.)

Comment: `hrefFun <- function(x){
  xpathSApply(x,"./a/@href")  
}` will grab just the actual link in case that is helpful #necropost